# Jquery error needs to be fixed: Error of invalid string JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

Trying to generate a piechart using dropdown menu and api but there is a json error for table showing invalid string.

Pie file

```
<?php

$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'techyari_demos';

// Create connection and select db
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
?>
<html>
<head>
  <!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart,table package.
  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart','table']});


  function drawItems(num) {
    var jsonPieChartData = $.ajax({
      url: "getpiechartdata.php",
      data: "q="+num,
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
    }).responseText;

    var jsonTableData = $.ajax({
      url: "gettabledata.php",
      data: "q="+num,
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
    }).responseText;

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var piechartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonPieChartData);
    var tabledata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonTableData);

    // Instantiate and draw our pie chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(piechartdata, {
      width: 700,
      height: 500,
      chartArea: { left:"5%",top:"5%",width:"90%",height:"90%" }
    });

    // Instantiate and draw our table, passing in some options.
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(tabledata, {showRowNumber: true, alternatingRowStyle: true});
  }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
  <select name="pt" onchange="drawItems(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a server:</option>
  <?php
   $dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'techyari_demos';
    // Make a MySQL Connection
    $con = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName) or die(mysql_error());
    mysqli_select_db($con,"techyari_demos") or die(mysqli_error());
    // Create a Query
    $sql_query = "SELECT id, servername FROM server ORDER BY servername ASC";
    // Execute query
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query) or die(mysqli_error());
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<option value='. $row['id'] . '>'. $row['servername'] . '</option>';
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
  ?>
  </select>
  </form>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <div id="table_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

getpiechartdata

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'techyari_demos';

$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

 $sql_query="SELECT * from entry";
 // $sql_query = "SELECT nickname, name, j2.label, j2.pointsum FROM user JOIN ( SELECT j1.user_id, j1.label, name, hover, j1.pointsum FROM activityfield JOIN ( SELECT user_id, activity_id, label, field_id , SUM( points.points ) AS PointSum FROM points JOIN activity ON points.activity_id = activity.id WHERE points.user_id=" . $q . " GROUP BY points.user_id, points.activity_id, activity.label, activity.field_id ORDER BY points.activity_id ASC ) AS j1 ON activityfield.id = j1.field_id ) AS j2 ON j2.user_id = user.id WHERE pointsum > 0 ORDER BY j2.pointsum DESC;";

  $con = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName)or die(mysql_error());;
  if (!$con){ die('Could not connect: ' .mysqli_error());}
  mysqli_select_db($con,"techyari_demos");
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
  echo "{ \"cols\": [ {\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"Name-Label\",\"pattern\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"}, {\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"PointSum\",\"pattern\":\"\",\"type\":\"number\"} ], \"rows\": [ ";
  $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result)or die(mysqli_error());;
  $row_num = 0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $row_num++;
    if ($row_num == $total_rows){
      echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" . $row['date'] . "-" . $row['sname'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":" . $row['status'] . ",\"f\":null}]}";
    } else {
      echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" . $row['date'] . "-" . $row['sname'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":" . $row['status'] . ",\"f\":null}]}, ";
    }
  }
  echo " ] }";
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

gettabledata

```
<?php
  $q=$_GET["q"];
 $dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'techyari_demos';


    $sql_query="SELECT date,sname,dbs,status,updatedby from entry";

  $con = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
  if (!$con){ die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
  mysqli_select_db($con,"techyari_demos");
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);

  echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" .'date'. "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" .'sname' . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" .'dbs' . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" .'status'. "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"".'updatedby'."\",\"f\":null}]}, ";

  $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" . $row['date'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . $row['sname'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . $row['dbs'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" .$row['status']."\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . $row['updatedby']. "\",\"f\":null}]}, ";
  }

 /* $result = mysqli_query($sql_query2);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" . $row['servername'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\" Total \",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . $row['dbs'] . "\",\"f\":null}]}";
  }
  echo " ] }";*/
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: On what line does the browser say the error is?

Comment: Why are you hand-coding all the JSON? Create an array/object and then use whatever PHP's JSON-encode function is on it.

Comment: Couple things, 1) Create a function or class that can retrieve your connection, doing your connection in random and repetitive spots is not idea, 2) Create functions in general to retrieve database arrays, makes your script manageable 3) Use `json_encode()` to create json, not your manual echos

Comment: Don't write the JSON yourself. Put your the data in arrays (or objects) and use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.json-encode.php). And your JSON will validate. Or, go in the opposite direction: learn to write your code directly in binary. Has the huge advantage of using only two keys and I hear you can get outrageous speeds at typing it.

Comment: @JosanIracheta   'var tabledata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonTableData);' showing me an error here due to the echo string.

Comment: @nnnnnn I need it from my database which varies and im fairly new to json so i'm trying to just make this work just to produce a piechart for my html/php page.

Comment: @Rasclatt    if you could help I'm fairly new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comments (and others comments), create some classes for re-use and readability, create a config for storage of re-usables, and then finally use `json_encode()` on arrays to create json strings for your ajax. I don't know if they are correctly formed, but they will be valid json strings:

/config.php

```
<?php
# Used for universal directory separator compatibility
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
# Store absolute paths for easy referencing
define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__);
define('VENDOR_DIR',ROOT_DIR.DS.'core'.DS.'vendors');
# Store database connection credentials this one spot only
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','techyari_demos');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','');
# Start user session
session_start();
# Create class autoloader so you don't have to worry about including manually
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $path = str_replace(DS.DS,DS,VENDOR_DIR.DS.str_replace('\\',DS,$class).'.php');
    if(is_file($path))
        include_once($path);
});
```

/core/vendors/Database.php

```
<?php
class Database
    {
        private static $con;
        private $query;
        # Assign database
        public static function init()
            {
                $db = new Database();
                return $db->getConnection();
            }
        # Creates database connection
        public function getConnection()
            {
                if(self::$con instanceof \PDO)
                    return $this;

                try {
                    self::$con = new \PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_NAME);
                }
                catch(\PDOException $e) {
                }

                return $this;
            }
        # Used to query database
        public function query($sql,$bind=false)
            {
                if(!empty($bind)) {
                    foreach($bind as $key => $value) {
                        $skey = ":$key";
                        $setBind[$skey] = $value;
                        $this->query = self::$con->prepare($sql);
                        $this->query->execute($setBind);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $this->query = self::$con->query($sql);
                }

                return $this;
            }
        # Used to fetch results from database
        public function getResults($single=false)
            {
                $row = array();
                while($result = $this->query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $row[] = $result;
                }

                if(empty($row))
                    return $row;

                return ($single)? $row[0] : $row;
            }
    }
```

/core/vendors/App.php

```
<?php
class App
    {
        # Easily return post values even if they don't exist without drawing errors
        public  function getPost($key=false)
            {
                if(!empty($key))
                    return (isset($_POST[$key]))? $_POST[$key] : false;

                return $_POST;
            }
        # Easily return get values even if they don't exist without drawing errors
        public  function getGet($key=false)
            {
                if(!empty($key))
                    return (isset($_GET[$key]))? $_GET[$key] : false;

                return $_GET;
            }
        # Easily return session values even if they don't exist without drawing errors
        public  function getSession($key=false)
            {
                if(!empty($key))
                    return (isset($_SESSION[$key]))? $_SESSION[$key] : false;

                return $_SESSION;
            }
        # Used to render pages
        public  function render($file)
            {
                ob_start();
                # Create instance of database
                $db = Database::init();
                # Include page to render
                include($file);
                # Assign view
                $data   =   ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
                # Return for echo
                return $data;
            }
    }
```

/index.php

```
<?php
if(!isset($this)) {
    include_once(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');
    echo (new App())->render(__FILE__);
    exit;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
  <!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart,table package.
  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart','table']});


  function drawItems(num) {
    var jsonPieChartData = $.ajax({
      url: "getpiechartdata.php",
      data: "q="+num,
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
    }).responseText;

    var jsonTableData = $.ajax({
      url: "gettabledata.php",
      data: "q="+num,
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
    }).responseText;

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var piechartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonPieChartData);
    var tabledata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonTableData);

    // Instantiate and draw our pie chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(piechartdata, {
      width: 700,
      height: 500,
      chartArea: { left:"5%",top:"5%",width:"90%",height:"90%" }
    });

    // Instantiate and draw our table, passing in some options.
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(tabledata, {showRowNumber: true, alternatingRowStyle: true});
  }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select name="pt" onchange="drawItems(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select a server:</option>
            <?php
            $servers = $db->query("SELECT id, servername FROM server ORDER BY servername ASC")->getResults();

            foreach($servers as $row) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['servername'] ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </form>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <div id="table_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

/getpiechartdata.php

```
<?php
if(!isset($this)) {
    include_once(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');
    echo (new App())->render(__FILE__);
    exit;
}

# Internally retrieve the get value
$q = $this->getGet("q");
# Run your general query
$results = $db->query("SELECT * from entry",array($q))->getResults(true);
# Set base array/object
$base = array(
    'cols'=>array(
        array(
            'id'=>'',
            'label'=>'Name-Label',
            'pattern' => '',
            'type'=>'string'
        ),
        array(
            'id'=>'',
            'label'=>'PointSum',
            'pattern' => '',
            'type'=>'number'
        )
    )
);
# Create default array
$base['rows'] = array();
# Loop results, building on base array/object
foreach($results as $row) {
    $base['rows'][] = array(
        'c'=>array(
            array(
                'v'=>$row['date'].' - '.$row['sname'],
                'f'=>NULL
            ),
            array(
                'v'=>$row['status'],
                'f'=>NULL
            )
        )
    );
}
# Return results
echo json_encode($base);
```